# Implementing ECSlidingViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to implement ECSlidingViewController & I am using segues in my storyboards. I am having a problem where the **MainViewController's viewDidLoad** is being called twice and

```
self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
```

is always getting set to null. More information.

1. LogIn Screen ( InitViewController ) ------through segue---------> MainViewController.

In my MainViewController I have the following code.

```
-(void)addMenuViewControllerWithGesture{
self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.075f;
self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f; 
self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[rsMenuViewController class]]) {

self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
}
}
```

In My InitViewController (LogIn)

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

MainViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;

// setting some values before going to the next view.

controller.id = 0;

controller.name = @"harish";

self.topViewController = controller;

}
```

By doing this, the **MainViewController's viewDidLoad** is getting called twice and the below value is always set to null.

```
self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
```

Hope it's clear. I am kind of stuck here and looking for a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. After a long, arduous experience, I figured it out. I asked a similar question here: [iOS Adding Menu Causes Crash When Not First View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089977/ios-adding-menu-causes-crash-when-not-first-view/18131243#18131243) and eventually answered it. I just recently came upon your question.

So let's say you have numerous files (.m and .h for each):

InitViewController

MenuViewController

MainViewController

SpeakersView

The objective was to switch from MainViewController using a button not on the slide menu to SpeakersView, but doing it directly caused the slide menu to be null, as was pointed out by Phillip Mills.

Instead, I put this in InitViewController.h, right underneath @Interface:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;
```

Then this under @implementation in InitViewController.m:

```
@synthesize location;
```

I originally had this under ViewDidLoad in InitViewController.m:

```
self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Main"];
```

I changed it to this:

```
if([location length] == 0){location = @"Main";}
self.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:location];
```

That way if the variable was empty, it defaulted to @"Main".

Then in MainView.m, where I execute the code after pressing the button, I have this:

```
InitViewController *ini;
ini = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Init"];
ini.location = @"Speakers";
```

And voilà, the view switches just fine to Speakers. More accurately, it switches to InitViewController which automatically switches to Speakers or whatever I set location to.

Hopefully this helps you.

Any questions, let me know.